# Does s3 overwrites the existing file upon creating a multiparty request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Assuming that I have a object with key X in S3 and then I call create a multipart request with the key X. I haven't uploaded the parts yet and I have not called complete multipart. I'm wondering at this point is the existing file (or object) overwritten? Or it is still unchanged until I call complete multipart request.

Sorry for the essay type question. I couldn't find any documentation about this.

Comment: What is stopping from trying it out?

Comment: Probably you searched for that one: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search about the *S3 consistency model*.

The S3 storage is eventual consistent for existing objects. It means, upon an update request, the existing (old) object version is returned until the new version is completely uploaded and replicated.